# Convert date without leading zeros in lubridate

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I have dates with the format

```
"7-10-2013 10:18"
```

However, when I try to use `lubridate::as_date` with them, I get this warning

> ```
> Warning message:
> All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
> ```

I think this is due to the fact that the date has no leading zeros.
How can I use `lubridate` in this case?

Comment: How about `strptime("7-10-2013 10:18", format = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')`? Your date is ambiguous (is the month a 7 as in American style, or date, as in most-other-places style?)

Comment: You could try `lubridate::mdy_hm("7-10-2013 10:18")` or `lubridate::dmy_hm("7-10-2013 10:18")` depending on which format (American/Not American)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass along the date-time format as a vector to `parse_date_time`

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

dat <- '7-10-2013 10:18'

parse_date_time(dat, "mdy HM")
#> [1] "2013-07-10 10:18:00 UTC"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>